# Java - Matching criteria on 3 collections to update 1 of them

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Consider the classes Site, Tag, and SiteTagRelation. I have a collection of each of these. For each site, I need to find all the corresponding tags by looking it up in the relation class, then add the matching tags to the site object.

It can be done with loops, but it is not elegant nor efficient. I'd like to find a one-liner solution with streams, but I fail to wrap my head around how to have the 3 collections co-exist in the same expression. Any hint on how to achieve this would be welcome.

```
public class Tag {
   private int id;
...
}

public class Site {
   private int id;
   Collection<Tag> tags;
...
}

public class SiteTagRelation {
   private int siteId;
   private int tagId;
...
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {
   Collection<SiteTagRelation> tagMapping = ...
   Collection<Site> sites = ...
   Collection<Tag> tags = ...

   // The expression I am struggling with should be here
   // From that point, all sites with a tag in sites should have a non-empty tags collection within itself
}
```

My solution with loops

```
private void enrichSite(Collection<Site> sites) {

        for(Site site : sites) {

            // Get all the matching relation
            Set<SiteTagRelation> matchingTagRelation = tagMapping.stream().filter(x -> x.getSiteId().equals(site.getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

            Set<Tag> matchingTags = new HashSet<Tag>();

            // Add each tag found to the collection
            for(SiteTagRelation mapping : matchingTagRelation) {
                Tag foundTag = this.tags().stream().filter(x -> x.getId().equals(mapping.getTagId())).findFirst().get();
                matchingTags.add(foundTag);
            }

            // Set the tags on the entity
            site.setTags(matchingTags);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "It can be done with loops" At the very least, show us your loop-based solution.

Comment: *It can be done with loops, but it is not elegant nor efficient.* ... Why do you think so?

Comment: @Michael: I have updated the post. My mistake. Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: @Naman: I suspect the stream API will have a better way of scanning the collections than my for loops

Comment: `equals`on `int` is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stream` solution would be the following, it's a kind of verbose but it does the same as the loops which should be preferred here for clarity

```
private void enrichSite(Collection<Site> sites) {
    sites.forEach(site ->
        site.setTags(tagMapping.stream().filter(x -> x.getSiteId().equals(site.getId()))
            .map(mapping -> this.tags.stream().filter(x -> x.getId().equals(mapping.getTagId())).findFirst().get())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

- you can"t use `equals` on `int`, so I assume your getters returned an `Integer`
- it's not safe to use `.get()` because you're sure a value is returned by the inner stream

---

Handle dangerous `get()` : you could give a fake `Tag` in case the inner stream returns nothing then filter on it

```
class Tag {
    private int id;
    // ...
    static Tag useless() {
        return new Tag(-1);
    }
}


private void enrichSite(Collection<Site> sites) {
    sites.forEach(site ->
        site.setTags(tagMapping.stream().filter(x -> x.getSiteId().equals(site.getId()))
            .map(mapping -> this.tags.stream().filter(x -> x.getId().equals(mapping.getTagId())).findFirst().orElseGet(Tag::useless))
            .filter(tag -> tag.getId() != -1)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I will toy with your implementation and will decide if I want to keep it or return to the loops